# How to log GuestAssignment Compliance Status' and output as a CSV

Tags: azure-policy, azure-compliance-policy

I have the following GuestConfiguration with several compliance status':
[image]

I want to be able to view these records in the log analytics workspace or something similar and eventually, output the results as a CSV for auditing.

---

I tried to use the policy assignment. However, this only gives me the overall "is the VM compliant": YES/NO. I'm trying to keep the compliance granularity per VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to view these records in the log analytics workspace or something similar and eventually, output the results as a CSV for auditing.

As there is no feature in `Log Analytics` to export query results to **Excel**, you can achieve the same scenario by using a `Logic App`.

Here is the steps to send Log Analytics query result to CSV using Logic Apps.

1. Run your `KQL query` in `Log Analytics`
2. Create a below design in `Logic App`

[image]

3.After running the `Logic App` flow, the `CSV` file generated by the `KQL query` has been uploaded to the `Storage account` as shown below.

[image]

**CSV File**

[image]

Reference: [Connect to Log Analytics or Application Insights from workflows in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-azure-monitor-logs#add-an-azure-monitor-logs-action)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I ended up solving this problem another way. I also used a KQL query. I used the Azure Resource Graph Explorer and queried the GuestAssignment resources from there.